# Interpreting Angles in Higher Dimensions

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

I am measuring the angles between vectors in the $n$-dimensional non-negative orthant (i.e., the non-negative subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$). $n$ is large. **I am wondering how much I can interpret angles in this space in absolute terms rather than relative terms.** For my project, angles are defined based on a standard Euclidean framework.

By relative terms, I mean I understand two vectors are closer to being parallel if the angle between them approaches 0. Thus, a ranking of angles to a comparison vector has a clear meaning.

But does knowing the specific value of an angle tell me anything meaningful in absolute terms? For instance, if I know the angle between $x$ and $y$ is less than 45 degrees, does that mean something compared to knowing that the angle between them is greater than 45 degrees?

For those curious about the context, I am setting a "maximum angle between" threshold for a data science application. I have various ideas about how to set this maximum angle from a statistical perspective, but I have found that using 45 degrees has produced quite reasonable results. I am wondering if this is an accident, or if I can actually interpret these angles meaningfully in higher dimensions in a way that I can explain to my colleagues.

Comment: For $n\gg1$, it will be much much more typical for two random vectors to be nearly orthogonal, i.e., something like an angle $<45^\circ$ becomes close to meaning "parallel for all practical purposes"

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, is that for random vectors with iid components that are mean zero? If all of the components are nonnegative, then depending on the distribution of the components, might it be more likely for smaller angles?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's an interesting approach and makes a lot of sense. However, if the angle between two random vectors is converging with probability to 90 degrees as $n$ increases, wouldn't that "parallel for all practical purposes" logic be true for any non-zero angle, not just 45 degrees?

Comment: Is your $n$ increasing, or fixed? Are all components of your vectors nonnegative, and are they drawn from some specific distribution?

Comment: @Joe $n$ is fixed. All components are nonnegative. I wasn't really thinking about them as being drawn from a distribution, but that was offered as one way to think about interpreting the angles. Ideally there would be some interpretation of the angles that could apply to any pair of vectors from this space, random or otherwise.

Comment: I think the main interpretation of the angle is the same for any $n$ - it is the angle between the vectors, the same angle that is between the vectors when you consider only the plane that they are in (assuming they are not parallel). If you want to use that angle for something, like a measure of similarity, then the interpretation would be based on the context - meaning how similar two vectors with an angle of $x$ degrees between them are would probably depend on the percentage of vectors less than that angle apart, but that would depend on the distribution, or you could just use uniform.

Comment: @Joe "I think the main interpretation of the angle is the same for any  - it is the angle between the vectors, the same angle that is between the vectors when you consider only the plane that they are in (assuming they are not parallel)." If you want to post that as the answer, I will accept it. It will suffice for my purposes. Thank you.

Comment: I think someone else can post a much better answer. I think of that as merely a comment, but if it's helps at all, that's great.